# AWS IoT thing automatically disconnects after subscribing

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, cron, raspberry-pi3, aws-iot

[image]

As we could see above, our AWS IoT endpoint disconnects automatically after subscribing to the topics. We're using Node.js for the connection and disconnection services, which updated the corresponding lambda function to publish the message. This problem only **occurs after the Pi restarts**. And I'm using **crontab** to schedule the autorun command for the endpoint. Any help in this regard would me much helpful. Thanks in advance.

The *disconnect lambda function* is given below, for reference.

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');

const iotdata = new AWS.IotData({
  endpoint: '**********-ats.iot.us-east-1.amazonaws.com'
});

exports.handler = function (event, context) {
  const clientID = event.clientId;
  console.log("Client id is " + clientID);
  const params = {
    topic: '$aws/things/' + clientID + '/shadow/update',
    payload: JSON.stringify({
      "state": {
        "reported": {
          "connected": false
        }
      }
    }),
    qos: 0
  };

  iotdata.publish(params, function (err, data) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    } else {
      console.log('Disconnected message published to \"' + params.topic + '\" as: ' + params.payload);
    }
  });
};
```